# Расположение виджетов в PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как разместить виджет `QListWidget` чтобы он отображался в правом углу окна

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_widows()

    def main_widows(self):
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test Create 2.0')
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
        choice_questions = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        choice_questions.resize(100, 105)
        choice_questions.move(0, 30)
        choice_questions.setSpacing(4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = Main()
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_widows()

    def main_widows(self):
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test Create 2.0')
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        left_main_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        left_main_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        left_main_frame.setMaximumWidth(300)
        right_main_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        right_main_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter.addWidget(left_main_frame)
        splitter.addWidget(right_main_frame)
        self.setCentralWidget(splitter)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
        self.choice_questions = QtWidgets.QListWidget(right_main_frame)
        self.choice_questions.resize(50, 55)
        self.choice_questions.move(0, 30)
        self.choice_questions.setSpacing(4)
        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        box.addWidget(self.choice_questions, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        wdg = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        wdg.setLayout(box)
        self.setCentralWidget(wdg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя `QBoxLayout` - компоновщики, можно задавать параметр выравнивания добавляемого виджета - `alignment`.

> void QBoxLayout::addWidget(QWidget *widget, int stretch = 0, Qt::Alignment alignment = Qt::Alignment())

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test Create 2.0')
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

        choice_questions = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        choice_questions.setFixedSize(100, 105) 
        # если размер должен быть фиксированным, а не определяться автоматически компоновщиком

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        box.addWidget(choice_questions, 0, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignRight)
        # выравнивание одновременно по верхней и правой границам

        wdg = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        wdg.setLayout(box)

        self.setCentralWidget(wdg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = Main()
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А если у меня фрейм указан как центральный виджет подредактировал вопрос

Comment: @Дмитрий, никакой разницы.

Comment: Тогда почему когда я добавляю `box` и `wdg` после чего я делаю `self.setCentralWidget(wdg)`  у меня пропадает окна фреймов

Comment: Лучше привести код, который приводит к такому поведению. Пока не совсем ясно, что и куда вы добавляете.

Comment: У вас там мешанина какая-то. Достаточно не создавать новый виджет, а добавить `layout` в нужный вам фрейм.